# Unable to connect to Oracle database from SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl

I am new to SSIS and ETL .I have a task to connect to oracle database from SSIS. But when I am giving source as OLEDB source and select Microsoft OLEDB  provider for Oracle along with server name and credentials, it throws me an error on testing the connection. i.e.
"Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed."

I have seen many posts and blogs but I could not  follow the steps and where I followed I could not connect. Hence I request you to please guide me in achieving the same.

Comment: This seems like a question you should be putting to whoever set you this task. Configuring servers is something not something we can do for you.

Comment: Likely culprits: 32 mode needed, default is 64 bit, driver configuration, and TNSNames. Yeah, that about covers the vast majority of issues

Comment: Also, check out the attunity add in, which might help get the right drivers installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You need to install an Oracle client of some description. Please do that and ask a specific question.

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client? 32/64-bit or this client has to be the same as your SSIS. Note, Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle does not work anymore with Oracle client 18c (or newer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle Client on the server that holds your SQL Server database. Oracle Client is free of charge.